# react-native flatlist detect when feed is loaded and rendered

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am implementing a react-native newsfeed with `FlatList` and I would like to detect then the feed is loaded, and the first few items rendered. The idea is that the splash page would be shown until the the newsfeed is rendered (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/01/18/implementing-twitters-app-loading-animation-in-react-native.html), at which point the splash feed would animate to the newsfeed. The question is where I do detect the `isRendered` event. My `FlatList` has two props that may be of interest:

```
class NewsFeed extends Component {

    state = { data: [] }

    loadData = async () => { ... }

     renderItem = ({ item }) => { ... }

    render () { 
       return <FlatList renderItem = {this.renderItem} data={this.state.data} />
    }
}
```

I tried flipping the the `isRendered` boolean flag as a last line in `loadData`, but after transitioning from the landing screen, it still takes a fraction of a second (sometimes) before the pictures render. So I flipped the `isRendered` boolean flag in `renderItem` function, and we never advance past the splash screen at all, meaning the function is never run.

Comment: Close the splash screen when api gets resolved. On getting success response from api close the splash screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check the value of isRendered in the render function. If isRendered is still false, you display the splash screen. Then if the boolean is true, you can begin the animation from this component and display the list right away as the data is already loaded. To make this work, call setState to flip the isRendered boolean in loadData as you were doing before, so the render function gets called again once the data is loaded. (And you can call the loadData function in componentDidMount as this will be called right away when the component gets mounted).

If the animation is being called from a different component, you might want to load the data there and do the isRendered check in that component's render function, and then possibly pass the data as a prop to make sure the NewsFeed component is already loaded with the data.